# Can't locate object method "newFromPng" via package "GD::Image"

Tags: perl, gd

I have a Perl script that throws the following message:

> Can't locate object method "newFromPng" via package "GD::Image" at
>   ../script/Perl/gestion-redimensionnement-images.pl line 271.

Here is the line 271 of the script:

```
my $gd_original =
    ( lc($extension) eq '.png' ) ? GD::Image->newFromPng($fichier_image)
  : ( lc($extension) eq '.gif' ) ? GD::Image->newFromGif($fichier_image)
  : ( $extension =~ m{\.jpe?g$}i ) ? GD::Image->newFromJpeg($fichier_image)
  :                                  GD::Image->new($fichier_image);
```

When I use `cpan` to check if `GD` is correctly installed, I get:

```
pan[1]> install GD
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.34)
Reading '/Users/romain/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 13 Jan 2014 18:53:02 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.76)
GD is up to date (2.50).
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

I'm running Perl v5.16 on a Mac under Mavericks.

Comment: I'm a Perl noob, so do not hesitate to ask me more details. I may have forgotten some information.

Comment: What about GD::Image `perl -MGD::Image -e 1`

Comment: When I run `perl -MGD::Image -e 1`, it display nothing. What kind of output should I expect?

Comment: That means you have the module installed. you are good there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you do not have libpng installed. GD will only offer the newFromPng(), newFromJpeg(), etc. methods if the underlying image libraries are present and available. You can test for the various formats using `can()`

```
use GD;
my $gd = GD::Image->new();
my $ok = $gd->can('png') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
print "$ok\n";
```

You can install libpng using MacPorts or manually from source.

Comment: Indeed, it return `No`. I will try to re-install libpng.

Comment: Ok, so my problem is related to the installation of libpng. I will create a dedicated question on SuperUser. Thanks

Comment: Question created on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/702248/installing-libpng-on-a-mac-with-maverick Still a mystery to me :(

Comment: Once you have installed libpng you will need to re-install GD. You can do that using MacPorts as well - package is called p5.14-gd (or whatever matches your perl version)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to use the [GD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GD) module?

```
use GD;
```

Try a trivially small example (using your own png file):

```
use GD;

my $fichier_image = 'my.png';
my $gd_original = GD::Image->newFromPng($fichier_image);
```

Comment: `use GD;` is defined in the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thanks. With this example, I get the same error: `perl test.pl`
`Can't locate object method "newFromPng" via package "GD::Image" at test.pl line 4.`